# Is it possible to have different web app and different for mobiles connected to Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I don't want to make all those checks if device is browser or iphone.

Would it work out if I connected one app styled for browser and one for mobile to the same Firebase project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add as many apps as you want to a Firebase project.  Just follow the procedure in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#register-app) to add each one.  They will each have access to the same resources in the project.